# Get Last 2 characters from column in DB2 AS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have a simple select query which is inside an openquery

```
SELECT 
    MyColumn,
    RIGHT(MyColumn,2)
FROM MyTable
```

however this gives error

> Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token ,2.  Token ,2
>   is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is ) ,.

In case someone has this issue.

```
RIGHT(MyColumn,2) gives token error

RIGHT(MyColumn, 2) is correct
```

Outcome of the actual query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linkServer, 'SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn, 2) FROM MyTable')
```

Comment: The following works on my 7.3:
`SELECT 
    MyColumn,
    RIGHT(MyColumn,2)
FROM (values '1234') MyTable(MyColumn);`
What's your IBM i version?

Comment: I found out the problem, It had to do with a space between comma and 2.... after i added this space, it worked. Not sure why, maybe because i'm using open query to run this query on AS400

Comment: It's always a good idea to put a space after a comma which is used as a parameter separator, because in different locales, or with different settings, the comma can also be used as the decimal point. This is the most likely reason for the syntax error. Not only is your code more portable with the space, it is arguably more readable. Come on, it's well past the age when we have to scrimp and save every byte. We can afford spaces after our separators. (We can even afford 4-digit years now! Can you believe it?!)

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with DB2 as that syntax works in embedded SQL, and in SQuirreL SQL client. But I have noticed that behavior sporadically in the DBeaver SQL client. Not in this case though.